# How to create object that contains a list of object in a single form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
public class Basket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Sharp { get; set; }
    public string Material { get; set; }
    public List<Fruit> Fruits { get; set; }
}


public class Fruit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Taste { get; set; }
}
```

With the above example, how could I create both Basket and Fruit in the same asp-form without using any JavaScript?

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Basket" asp-action="Create">
    <input asp-for="Material" />
    <input asp-for="Sharp" />

    @*I would like to also create custom amounts of new Fruit in this form.*@

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If my razor form is defined as the above example, how could I create custom amounts of Fruit and create Basket at the same form? It is possible to avoid using JavaScript in this case?

Comment: what have you already tried ?

Comment: I have made a form containing the primitive fields of Basket but I got stuck when I implementing the List of Fruit part. I wonder if asp.net mvc have primitive form component to handle this case.

Comment: can you put the code what you already tried ?

Comment: So you are trying to build a model which will contains List of `Basket` and `Fruit` together right? Why don't you try a `custom view Model`?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Could you please provide some code example with custom view Model?

Comment: A `Custom View Model` is sometimes referred to as a MVVM. It's a combination of POCO's. So create a class called `BasketOfFruits` that has an one line of code, an instance or a List<> of `Basket`. This is only half the answer though you need to persist the Fruits added. Let me solve many questions in one go, do this official asp.net core tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is possible to avoid using JavaScript in this case?

Based on your scenario and current architecture what you need to do is, there should be a `table` where you would be adding your `fruit object` as it's a `List<Fruit> Fruit` kind of. As per your given code, your output should be as below:

[image]

*So, I would say, `Javascript` would make it easier. If you would like to avoid `javascript` it wouldn't be impossible but would be costly and complex.*

> how could I create custom amounts of Fruit and create Basket at the
> same form?

You could follow the below steps to achieve what you are trying to implement.

**View:**

```
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.Basket

<form method="post" asp-controller="Yonny" asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Material" class="col-md-2 form-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Material" class="col-md-6 form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Material" class="form-span-error"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom:20px">
        <label asp-for="Sharp" class="col-md-2 form-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Sharp" class="col-md-6 form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Sharp" class="form-span-error"></span>
    </div>
    @*I would like to also create custom amounts of new Fruit in this form.*@
    <div style="padding-bottom:20px">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddRow()">Add Fruit</button>
    </div>
   
    <div id="dataTable">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Color</th>
                    <th>Taste</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="FruitList" data-count="0">
              
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
</form>

@section Scripts {
<script>
    /*
         . Hidding table on load
    */
      document.getElementById('dataTable').style.display ='none';

      function AddRow()
      {
          var countVal = parseInt($('#FruitList').attr('data-count'));
          var html = '';
          html += '<tr>';
          html += '<td><input type="text" name="Fruits[' + countVal + '].Id" class="form-control"/></td>';
          html += '<td><input type="text" name="Fruits[' + countVal + '].Color" class="form-control"/></td>';
           html += '<td><input type="text" name="Fruits[' + countVal + '].Taste" class="form-control"/></td>';
          html += '</tr>';

          $('#FruitList').append(html);
          countVal += 1;
          $('#FruitList').attr('data-count', countVal);
      /*
         . Showing table when adding item into 
      */
           document.getElementById('dataTable').style.display ='block';
       
      }
</script>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
     [HttpPost]
     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Create(
     [Bind("Id,Material,Sharp,Fruits")] DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.Basket basket)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Save Basket
                _context.Add(basket);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                //Add Fruits List
                foreach (var item in basket.Fruits)
                {
                    _context.Add(item);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
            }
            return View(basket);
        }
```

**Note:**

If you somehow got null data while sending request to `controller` make sure your `binding property` that is `Bind("Id,Material,Sharp,Fruits")` are same as `name="Fruits[' + countVal + '].Id"` inside the `javascript function`

**Output:**

[image]